# Handing different firebase login options

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on an Android App which handles google,facebook as well as twitter login using `Firebase-Realtime Database` but I don't know how to implement three different logins inside single activity.

Comment: Use different result codes or check the contents of `data`

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: is you create the app on firebase and complete the connection between app and firebase using SHA1 fingerpriny

Comment: Well, show more of your code. How did you get to `onActivityResult`? Where did you `startActivityForResult`? You can just set a breakpoint in there to inspect `data`

Comment: startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN); ->>> For Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use different requestCode like below code

```
 public static final int RC_TWITTER_LOGIN = 2;
 public static final int RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN = 1;

  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN) {
        /* This was a request by the Google API */
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleLoginClicked = false;
        }
        mGoogleIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == RC_TWITTER_LOGIN) {
        options.put("oauth_token", data.getStringExtra("oauth_token"));
        options.put("oauth_token_secret", data.getStringExtra("oauth_token_secret"));
        options.put("user_id", data.getStringExtra("user_id"));
        authWithFirebase("twitter", options);
    } else {
        /* Otherwise, it's probably the request by the Facebook login button, keep track of the session */
        mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

you can refer full code demo [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android)

Comment: Did you check demo which i refer

Comment: download the demo and run the code. That will help you.

Comment: start activity method call like  startActivityForResult(recover, RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);

Comment: I don't want to use twitterj.Is there another way of doing so.

Comment: Make twitter button visibility gone. also remove the code of twitter from your activity

Answer (score 2):

My Login Activity please check that code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Login XML

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.firebase.LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_w_h"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_w_h"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_forgot_password"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not relevant answer.